# Creating pockets using bmesh/python

Tags: python, bmesh

I'm trying to figure out how to create a pocket using bmesh (Python Console). The regular workflow to create the example below could be as follows —

[image]

Add a Cube in Object Mode, tab into Edit Mode and select an arbitrary Face. Then, use the following steps —

1. Extrude the selected Face
2. Scale the selected Face
3. Extrude the selected Face again
4. Translate the selected Face

The question is *how to create the same result using bmesh?* To get started in the Python Console,

```
import mathutils
import bmesh

me = bpy.context.edit_object.data
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)
```

Let's just extrude an arbitrary Face and continue from there

```
f = bm.faces[2]  
d = bmesh.ops.extrude_discrete_faces(bm, faces=[f])
f = d['faces'][0]
```

Now `f` refers to the extruded Face. The next step is to scale the extruded Face. To keep things simple, let's assume the normal of the selected Face is parallel to the x-axis. The following code only works as intended if the cube is centered around the origin

```
bmesh.ops.scale(bm, vec=mathutils.Vector((1,.5,.5)), verts=f.verts)
```

because `bmesh.ops.scale()` seems to use the global (world) coordinates. Is it possibible to use local coordinates instead?

Another option might be to use `bmesh.ops.inset_individual()`, though unfortunately it does not create the 4 trapezoid Faces.

The last two steps are straightforward, just another `bmesh.ops.extrude_discrete_faces()` followed by `bmesh.ops.translate()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to work, in edit mode (for the simplicity of example)

```
import bpy
import bmesh

obj = bpy.context.edit_object
me = obj.data
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)

face = [bm.faces.active]

bmesh.ops.inset_region(bm, faces=face, thickness=0.4)
bmesh.ops.inset_region(bm, faces=face, thickness=0, depth=-0.5)

bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me, True)
```

[image]

Regarding `bmesh.ops.scale()`, it takes a `space` argument which is a matrix to base the operation on. If you are comfortable generating matrices then that's probably enough, but if not then see this snippet.

Template can be found at TextEditor->Templates->Python->Bmesh Simple

```
import bpy
import bmesh
from mathutils import Vector, Matrix

# Get the active mesh
me = bpy.context.object.data
bm = bmesh.new()   # create an empty BMesh
bm.from_mesh(me)   # fill it in from a Mesh

bm.edges.ensure_lookup_table()
bm.verts.ensure_lookup_table()

e = bm.edges[0]

mid_invert = (e.verts[0].co + e.verts[1].co) * -0.5
edge_matrix = Matrix()
edge_matrix[0][3] = mid_invert[0]
edge_matrix[1][3] = mid_invert[1]
edge_matrix[2][3] = mid_invert[2]

factor = (0.5, 0.5, 0.5)
bmesh.ops.scale(bm, vec=factor, space=edge_matrix, verts=e.verts)

# Finish up, write the bmesh back to the mesh
bm.to_mesh(me)
bm.free()  # free and prevent further access
```

I'm almost positive that there is an easier way to construct the `space` matrix, given a simple 3-vector, rather than my verbose approach.

Comment: Thanks! I completely overlooked `bmesh.ops.inset_individual()` and `bmesh.ops.inset_region()`. Still curious though, is it possible to use `bmesh.ops.scale()` using local coordinates?

Comment: I think so, you have to pass a matrix to the scale operator. http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_74_5/bmesh.ops.html?highlight=bmesh.ops.scale#bmesh.ops.scale. Ask a fresh question, I might have time to answer!

Comment: https://gist.github.com/zeffii/71862f5b1cad1bf1d2c1 here's an example that scales edges with reference to their own matrix..

Comment: @Ailurus I've extended the answer to include `bpy.ops.scale()`

Comment: Cheers. I added some additional information on using `bmesh.ops.scale()` in a separate answer.

Answer (score 2):

Figured out how to use `bmesh.ops.scale()` to scale a Face the same way as in Edit Mode. As it might be useful to others I thought I'd post it here.

First we have to create a translation matrix **T** that maps the centroid of our Face of interest to the origin. This part is straightforward — assuming the necessary modules are loaded and we have a reference to our Face of interest, e.g. like this,

```
import mathutils
import bmesh

obj = bpy.context.edit_object
me = obj.data
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)

k = 2
face = bm.faces[k]
```

the translation matrix **T** can be created as follows:

```
T = mathutils.Matrix.Translation(-face.calc_center_median())
```

Note the minus — we're mapping *to the origin*, not the other way around.

Next, we have to create a rotation matrix **R** that maps the normal **n** of our Face of interest to the **z**-axis. In order to create **R**, we require the axis of rotation. This is simply the cross-product between **n** and **z** (in this order). The angle between the two vectors can be determined in various ways, e.g. using the `mathutils.Vector.angle()` function or `acos(n.dot(z))`, after all both vectors are unit vectors. Note that a positive angle refers to counter-clockwise rotation in Blender.

```
n = face.normal
z = mathutils.Vector((0,0,1))
axis = n.cross(z)
angle = n.angle(z)

R = mathutils.Matrix.Rotation(angle, 4, axis)
```

Finally, we have to combine **T** and **R**. The order is important — first translation, then rotation. The example below scales the Face by 60% just like in Edit Mode.

```
bmesh.ops.scale(bm, vec=mathutils.Vector((.6,.6,1)), space=R*T, verts=face.verts)
```